# Three free moves, three more moves, mate

Tags: chess, retrograde-analysis

This morning, at the coffee corner in our office, I met a colleague who mentioned he'd be joining a chess club. So I asked him: "And, how was your first evening at the chess club?"

"Well, it was a rather short one.", he replied, looking rather sad.

"Oh, what happened?"

"I had the black pieces. Because I was new, my opponent let me make three moves for free. You told me king safety is important, so I first concentrated on getting my king into safety in the corner. However, after we both made three more moves, I was still mated on the next move."

I thought back to when I showed him the [smothered mate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smothered_mate). I said: "King in the corner, let me see... did you let your king be smothered perhaps?"

"No, my bishop's pawns were still in their original positions. I still had all my pawns, for what it's worth."

Unfortunately, I had to rush to a meeting, so I couldn't ask him for the complete game. I didn't see him again that day, but on the way back home I was able to figure out which moves were played. That was a sad loss indeed ...

---

**TL;DR:** Construct a chess game where

- White skips the first three moves
- Otherwise, play continues normally
- White gives mate on the 7th move
- The black king ends in the corner
- Black still has 8 pawns, including two on c7 and f7

<sup>(story inspired by [previous](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74183/11110) [questions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74080/11110); the puzzle itself is original)</sup>

---

This puzzle is an entry in the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #40: Retrograde Analysis](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6490/fortnightly-topic-challenge-40-retrograde-analysis).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this one which I think works:

> 1... g6
>  2... Bh6
>  3... Nf6
>  4. d4 O-O
>  5. Qd2 Kh8
>  6. Qxh6  Ne8
>  7. Qxf8#

Final position

> [image]

Comment: Yep, that was the intended solution. Congratulations for finding it so fast!